# Conditional PDF of Normal Distribution $X \sim N(0,1)$ , given $X>0$

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

Given a Normal Random variable $X \sim N(0,1)$. I need to find the following:

1. CDF, PDF of $X$, given $X>0$
2. $E[X|X>0]$ and $Var(X|X>0)$

I have done the following for CDF:

$$P(X\le x|X>0) = \frac{P(0 \le X \le x)}{P(X>0)} = 2\Phi(x) - 1$$

And, hence conditional PDF will be : $$f_X(x|X>0) = 2.f_X(x), x \in [0, \infty)$$

Intuitively looking at Var(X|X>0), it will be same as Var(X), since Normal Distribution is a symmetrical one and the measure of variation around central tendency will be same even if $X>0$ because $Range_X$ has become half too.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the conditional density, why not use it? You have

$$E[X|X>0] = \int_0^\infty xf_X(x|X>0) dx = 2\int_0^\infty f_X(x)dx,$$

and a similar formula for $\operatorname{Var}(X|X>0)$. You will find that the conditional variance will not be the same as the unconditional variance. To provide some intuition for this, we know that a standard Gaussian random variable lies in $(-1,1)$ with probability roughly $70\%$, so conditional on $X>0$, we should have $X\in(0,1)$ with probability roughly $70\%$. This suggests a smaller variance, which you can verify.

Comment: Ok I will verify that. But the conditional pdf is correct, right?

Comment: Indeed... I am getting expectation as $\sqrt{2/\pi}$ and variance as $1-2/\pi$

Comment: The PDF is correct, and you are getting the correct expectation and variance!

Comment: Sorry, I got a really pedantic question. The lower bound on the integral is $zero$. Is this because we're conditioning on $X > 0$, or is this because $f_{X|X>0} = 0$ if $X < 0$? I've always thought it was the latter, but just wanted to confirm

Comment: @student010101 Both! Or rather, because $f_{X|X>0}(x) = 0$ for $x\le0$, which is of course a consequence of the conditioning.